# Is there any equivalent of JVisualVM on DotNET?

Tags: .net, jvm, equivalent, jvisualvm

I would like to know if there is an equivalent of the excellent Java JVisualVM (included with JDK, the command is "jvisualvm") on the DotNet platform ?

JVisualVM is a great tool that allows developers and admins to have really useful monitoring on any running Java application, here is some features that it has :

- [Graphical view of the threads status](http://kedare.free.fr/SShots/Java/JVisualVM/jvisualvm_threads.png)
- [Memory/CPU graphs](http://kedare.free.fr/SShots/Java/JVisualVM/jvisualvm_monitor.png)
- [Live heap dump](http://kedare.free.fr/SShots/Java/JVisualVM/jvisualvm_heapdump.png)
- [CPU/Memory profiling](http://kedare.free.fr/SShots/Java/JVisualVM/jvisualvm_cpu.png)
- [Garbage Collector / JIT utilization graphs](http://kedare.free.fr/SShots/Java/JVisualVM/jvisualvm_gc.png)
- JMX calls

Is there any equivalent on DotNet ?

Thank you !

Comment: That looks really cool, I'mma set your post as a favorite!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what JVisualVM does, but it seems you are looking for this

http://www.red-gate.com/products/index.htm > .NET Developer Tools

Comment: To make it simple: JVisualVM monitors the Java Virtual Machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual studio in debug -> performance and diagnositcs
Or using a miscrosoft tool : https://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/ 
But it is not at the level of jvisualvm...