# .net equivalent of visualvm

Tags: .net, out-of-memory, visualvm

I am currently working on an application in VB.NET im my spare time and have just received an  [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx).

As I am currently working in Java at work, I frequently use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to diagnose any thread/memory issues.

So I am now wondering, is there .NET or Visual Studio 2010 equivalent of VisualVM?  Ideally free tools.

Just noticed similar thread to this:

[Is there any equivalent of JVisualVM on DotNET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217344/is-there-any-equivalent-of-jvisualvm-on-dotnet)

But this does not give me an answer.

Thanks in advance,

Andez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not Free**

.NET Memory Profiler: http://memprofiler.com/

JetBrains dotTrace : http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/index.html

RedGate ANTS Memory Profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

SciTech Memory Profiler: http://www.scitech.se/

**Free**

MS CLR Profiler: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273

I would suggest you take a trial and figure out what works best for you. But personally I have use the RedGate ANTS Profiler and is has been just awesome for my needs.

Comment: Thanks Jaimal.  Will check them out.  We've used the Redgate SQL Server tools at work which are nice, but not seen the .Net ones before.  But the tools are for myself, so at a few hundred pounds I need to be careful what I get.  +1 btw